# Backbone templates in production

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, templating

From https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jax-cellar/blob/master/WebContent/js/utils.js:

```
tpl = {

// Hash of preloaded templates for the app
templates: {},

// Recursively pre-load all the templates for the app.
// This implementation should be changed in a production environment. All the template files should be
// concatenated in a single file.
loadTemplates: function(names, callback) {

    var that = this;

    var loadTemplate = function(index) {
        var name = names[index];
        console.log('Loading template: ' + name);
        $.get('tpl/' + name + '.html', function(data) {
            that.templates[name] = data;
            index++;
            if (index < names.length) {
                loadTemplate(index);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

    loadTemplate(0);
},

// Get template by name from hash of preloaded templates
get: function(name) {
    return this.templates[name];
}
};
```

Should I do something like

```
$.get('tpl/all-tpls.html', function(data) { }
```

to get all the html templates? Wouldn't that be unnecessarily fetching a bunch of html? Our app is being built in Java and we are using https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin to minify and combine our js and css files. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript

Comment: Our backend runs on java.

Comment: Still, this question belongs to JavaScript. If you use Java in your server side, good for you! but that doesn't make it fit as a Java question at all.

Comment: If you look at then end of my question, the link is to a Maven plugin that does something similar to what I'm after, only for JS and CSS files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes. You should load all the templates initially on app load so they available. In production, this can be combined with serving correct far-future expiry headers so that the templates are cached for the user between visits (i.e. 1 year). You can then bust the cache using a query string, something like `tpl/all-tpls.html?v=001`

**Longer answer**:

For performance reasons you will most likely want to aim to reduce the loading time and number of requests as much as possible. This will also help the app feel more responsive, if there is less delay when loading a new section if the template is already available.

Combining your templates and caching them will be effective until your app grows very large. At that point, you may wish to break down the loading - for example into groups based around the sections of your app. However, consider this a lifecycle performance optimization - don't pre-optimize just for the sake of it.

Comment: Even better would be to precompile the templates into Javascript and serve it concatenated with the rest of the app.